# PHP + mySQL: Prepare, bind_param not working as I'd expect it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'll put here two examples where `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare()` + `$stmt->bind_param()` deny to work and I can't see for myself why.
Not working:

```
if ($stmt = $mySQLi->prepare("DROP DATABASE ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $db_name);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result();
}
```

Current working workaround:

```
 if ($stmt = $mySQLi->prepare("DROP DATABASE $db_name")) {
        //$stmt->bind_param('s', $db_name);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result();
 }
```

Not working:

```
if ($stmt = $strSQLi->prepare("SELECT ? FROM Strings.texts WHERE keyName = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', strtolower($lang), strtolower("help_".$key));
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
}
```

Current working workaround:

```
if ($stmt = $strSQLi->prepare("SELECT {strtolower($lang)} FROM EVEStrings.texts WHERE keyName = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', strtolower("help_".$key));
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
}
```

Any idea WHY?

Comment: you can not bind table name,table column name. You only can bind attributes values in binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `mysqli::prepare()` is working. It's completely written in the documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
Note:
```

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column
>   names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a
>   SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator
>   such as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because
>   it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not
>   allowed to compare marker with NULL by ? IS NULL too. In general,
>   parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML)
>   statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

This part mostly: **they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names)**

The idea of binding parameters it that you are sending to the database engine the query and in the runtine it binds the values you have given. If the table is not specified, the engine cannot build a valid statement, thus to continue executing the query and bind params is impossible.

I would not suggest to use dynamic table names in general, whether it is safe or not. However, if you really insist to do it, do not let the user to decide that. Decide the `{strtolower($lang)}` on application level (i.e. from an array), not from the user input.

Comment: I'm not letting the user to put anything in query. $lang is result of another fetch from DB. But thank you for your answer! Very informative! Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from PDO (and I think it's the same for mysqli) this can't be done.

`bind_param` and `bind_value()` can only bind values, not table or column names.

You have to filter your data manually, maybe with a whitelist method.